# How do I change the default text font in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, editor, default

How do I set the default font size in Eclipse?

I'd like to set a default for unrecognized file types, like shell scripts and text files.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Software Salariman has posted a solution - "[Change Default Text Font in Eclipse](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2008/09/change-default-text-font-in-eclipse.html)".

The default font is set in:

Menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and fonts* → *Basic/Text Font*.

Comment: It's funny it's located under "Basic" considering that Basic is a programming language.

Comment: Also font type and size can be changed but not color, if I am right

Comment: @HelloGoodbye my thought exactly. Even if it weren't, there are established terms like "general", "defaults" etc. But then SO would feel so lonely...

Comment: The problem I am having is that when I switch workspaces, the changes I made to the font settings seem to completely reset. I am wondering how I make my changes the actual default settings?

Answer (score 1):

Use menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font* → *Edit*.

Here you can change your preferred font and size.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to this, using Eclipse v4.3 (Kepler), I have just opened up Eclipse on my shiny new works laptop and everything was in **Segoe UI** font - Bizarre.

I used the following to reset everything as the previous examples didn't seem to format XML and a few other types very well...

*General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Structured Text Editors* → *Structured Text Editor Text font (overrides...)*

Once I set this to Consolas it seems to have set everything to Consolas :)